# Rewrite rule accepting #

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have the current RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9a-zA-Z-\s-:]+)(/?)$ search.php?search=$1 [NC,L,NE]
```

I'm wanting to have an url like this /search/#ff2266/, to accept hex (with the #) colors in the url and then have this value in the $_GET['search'] variable. But not only this, but I'm having problem with the #.

Is there any way i could do something like this: ([#0-9a-zA-Z-\s-:]+) ?

I've tried the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)(/?)$ search.php?search=$1 [NC,L,NE]
```

And then in the search.php the following code:

```
echo "var_dump($_GET): ";
var_dump($_GET);
```

and with the url /search/#f44336/ the result is:

```
var_dump(Array): array(0) { }
```

Comment: Can you edit and give an example of what you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, the part of a URI after the # is called "fragment" and is by definition only available/processed on client side (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

On the client side, this can be accessed using javaScript with window.location.hash.

If you want to access that number in your search file, you could pass it to there without the hash char and use it that way.

Comment: Yea, i think i will have to use that without the #. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, sir! I hope I helped.